# RSpec: How to test a helper method that calls a private helper method from the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

Here's what I have:

An application helper method that calls a controller helper method (private) from it.

Code:

**ApplicationHelper:**

```
def ordenar(coluna, titulo = nil)  
    titulo ||= coluna.titleize  
    css_class = (coluna == **coluna_ordenacao**) ? "#{**direcao_ordenacao**}" : "ordenavel"  
    direcao = (coluna == **coluna_ordenacao** and **direcao_ordenacao** == "asc") ? :desc : :asc  
    link_to titulo, {:sort => coluna, :direction => direcao}, {:class => css_class}  
end
```

**ApplicationController:**

```
helper_method :coluna_ordenacao, :direcao_ordenacao  
private  
def coluna_ordenacao  
    return params[:sort] if params[:sort] and params[:sort].split(' ').size == 1  
    return :created_at  
end  

def direcao_ordenacao  
    return %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : :desc  
end
```

And here is the problem: The `coluna_ordenacao` and `direcao_ordenacao` methods can't be called from RSpec, it gives me the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `coluna_ordenacao' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x7fbf0a9fe3d8>
```

Is there any way for that to work? Btw I'm testing the helper, not the controller

Comment: please show us your spec

Comment: may be apropos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448063/how-do-you-test-a-rails-controller-method-exposed-as-a-helper-method

Answer (score 2):

You can access private methods in tests using `.send(:private_methods_name)`

[see documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send)